# Shadertoy shader port to Metal slow on iOS

Tags: ios, macos, 3d, shader, metal

I'm trying to learn Metal shaders so I ported this mountain generation shader I found on Shadertoy to Metal.

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/llsGW7

The port works, but is very slow on iOS. It is reasonably fast on OS X but gets slower when I increase the window size. It is also slow within an OS X playground.

I've done the tutorials on MetalKit.org and read the apple docs on the metal shading language but feel like I'm a bit conceptually lacking of how everything is working under the hood. If there is anything that jumps out in this code that is obviously slowing things down I would be very grateful to learn. I am not sure if the slowdown is due to the shader code itself, or the way it's all set up.

Here's the metal shader:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

constexpr sampler textureSampler(coord::normalized,
                             address::repeat,
                             min_filter::linear,
                             mag_filter::linear,
                             mip_filter::linear );

kernel void compute(texture2d<float, access::write> output [[texture(0)]],
                texture2d<float, access::sample> input [[texture(1)]],
                constant float &timer [[buffer(0)]],
                uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
int width = input.get_width();
int height = input.get_height();

float2 uv = float2(gid) / float2(width, height);

float4 p = float4(uv,1,1)-0.5;

p.y = -p.y;
float4 d = p*0.5;
float4 t;
float4 c;

p.z += timer*200;
d.y-=0.2;

for(float i=1.7;i>0.0;i-=0.002) {
    float s=0.5;

    t = input.sample(textureSampler,0.3+p.xz*s/3e3) / (s+=s);
    // this makes it purple
    c = float4(1.0,-0.9,0.8,9.0)+d.x-t*i;

    //        c = float4(1.0,0.9,0.8,9.0)+d.x-t*i;
    if (t.x > p.y*.01+1.3) {
        break;
    }
    p += d;
}
output.write(c, gid);
}
```

and here is a subclass of MTKView I'm using to render the shader

```
import Cocoa
import MetalKit

class MetalView: MTKView {

var queue: MTLCommandQueue!
var cps: MTLComputePipelineState!
var timer: Float = 0
var timerBuffer: MTLBuffer!
var shaderName: String!
var texture: MTLTexture!

required public init(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    self.framebufferOnly = false
    self.preferredFramesPerSecond = 60
    registerShaders()
    setupTexture()

}

func setupTexture() {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "texture", ofType: "jpg")
    let textureLoader = MTKTextureLoader(device: device!)
    texture = try! textureLoader.newTexture(withContentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!), options: nil)
}

func registerShaders() {
    device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
    queue = device!.makeCommandQueue()
    do {
        let library = device!.newDefaultLibrary()!
        let kernel = library.makeFunction(name: "compute")!
        cps = try device!.makeComputePipelineState(function: kernel)
    } catch let e {
        Swift.print("\(e)")
    }
    timerBuffer = device!.makeBuffer(length: MemoryLayout<Float>.size, options: [])

}

override public func draw(_ dirtyRect: CGRect) {

    if let drawable = currentDrawable {
        let commandBuffer = queue.makeCommandBuffer()
        let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder()
        commandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(cps)
        commandEncoder.setTexture(drawable.texture, at: 0)
        commandEncoder.setTexture(texture, at: 1)
        commandEncoder.setBuffer(timerBuffer, offset: 0, at: 0)
        update()
        let threadGroupCount = MTLSizeMake(8, 8, 1)
        let threadGroups = MTLSizeMake(drawable.texture.width / threadGroupCount.width, drawable.texture.height / threadGroupCount.height, 1)
        commandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadGroups, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadGroupCount)
        commandEncoder.endEncoding()
        commandBuffer.present(drawable)
        commandBuffer.commit()
    }
}
func update() {
    timer += Float(1.0 / TimeInterval(self.preferredFramesPerSecond))
    let bufferPointer = timerBuffer.contents()
    memcpy(bufferPointer, &timer, MemoryLayout<Float>.size)

}

}
```

Comment: I suspect is it because of the timer you passed in, the shadertoy's iGlobalTime is "Current time in seconds", maybe you can try to pass in your timer something like this.

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected the timer interval. This change did not change the performance on iOS, though.

Comment: The [docs for `MTLComputeCommandEncoder`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/metal/mtlcomputecommandencoder) show sample code for calculating the ideal threads-per-group and thread-groups-per-grid for a grid matching a 2D image's size. You are hard-coding the former, which may be non-optimal. There are some weird things in the code, such as repeated calculation of `c` while only the last is used, and the bizarre `s` variable, but the compiler should optimize those away. Ultimately, the real expense is probably the repeated sampling of the texture.

Comment: I've isolated the issue. The break in the loop is the main problem affecting performance, followed by the loop itself. However, the break is also integral to how the effect is being generated. The original shader is from a Shadertoy competition for a shader that fits in a tweet, so is not really a model for good programming style.